# Is there a way to detect only the cells displayed on the screen when using List in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Is it possible to detect the cell (or array position) of the List currently displayed on the View screen from among the 100 Items as shown below?

Also, at that time, I would like to get the position of the cell in detail, such as some cells that are half hidden from the screen at the top and bottom.

```
struct DemoList: View {
    // 1.
    @State private var items: [Item] = (0..<100).map { Item(title: "Item #\($0)") }

    // 2.
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(items) { item in
                Text(item.title)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a starting point. But beware that List always keeps one "buffer" cell before .onAppear/.onDisappear kick in.

```
        List {
            ForEach(items) { item in
                GeometryReader { geo in
                    Text(item.title)
                        .onAppear {
                            print(item.title, geo.frame(in: .global))
                        }
                        .onDisappear {
                            print(item.title, "---")
                        }
                }
            }
        }
```

A more sophisticated approach would use `PreferenceKey`. I recommend this (look for "GridInfoPreference"): https://swiftui-lab.com/impossible-grids/

Comment: I did not get why would GeometryReader needed there(like 120 percent unnecessary code and extra load for cpu), also using onAppear and onDisappear is not even an option for closed source code of apple List, since we do not not know when acutely would onAppear would called, or even onDisappear. You are treating Apple List, like you know how it is working undercover, which unfortunately can not be an effective code or approach.

Comment: Thank you. I hope to get started. I feel like I can get details such as the points hidden from the height of each cell.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ‘onAppear’ modifier as `Text(text).onAppear {}`
Since iOS 15 there have been improvements around that modifier